# Can a TRUNCATE or DROP table ever be very time consuming?

Tags: mysql, blocking, truncate, drop-table

A couple of months ago, I discovered in a (not so well maintained) database a totally useless table containing 430 million unindexed rows, growing by about 80 000 rows per day.

It was a top candidate for removal. However, I never got the opportunity to achieve this (a.k.a. not the priority). I did not even have the opportunity to try to delete it in a weekly refreshed dev database.

I was wondering whether a simple TRUNCATE or DROP could ever be very time-consuming? I mean, could this operation block a production environment for several minute like DELETEs can when they are not well written. Or are these safe operations?

Comment: Yes both the commands can be blocked on prod environment, it would be advisable to run it when nothing is accessing the table. A very good read on [This SE Thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/why-use-both-truncate-and-drop)

Comment: That is not my question. I think you missed the point. I would - of course - perform the TRUNCATE/DROP when I am sure nothing is accessing the table.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and the behaviour of TRUNCATE is quite different between different DBMS products and a DELETE statement usually doesn't "block" anything other than UPDATEs or other DELETEs.

Comment: It was a MySql database.

Comment: @JérômeVerstrynge I do not think I missed your question that is why I added the link it had complete details, it is your mistake you did not tagged it with proper RDBMS. The answer is for SQL Server and you said database is MySQL anyways I believe the operations would almost be same

Comment: @JérômeVerstrynge - Why did you accept the MSSql Answer?  (You can move the checkmark to another Answer.)

Comment: Yea, I agree with @RickJames I'm going to VTC this because I'm not sure the question is right for the answer it has me confused. Totally cool to ask a question on Microsoft SQL, or a generic question on implementations, but if you're going to ask a specific question on MySQL you need to pick an answer that addresses it.

Comment: If the table is growing, I wouldn't just remove it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, could [TRUNCATE OR DROP TABLE] block a production environment for several minute like DELETEs can

For Microsoft SQL Server, in rare cases yes.

Both TRUNCATE and DROP are "metadata only" operations, meaning that they just involve a few changes to the internal catalog tables.  So they are never resource-intensive.  But they both require Schema Modification locks (Sch-M) on the table.

When you request a Sch-M lock you have to wait until all incompatible locks are released.  Every query that references the table needs an incompatible Sch-S lock.  After you request the Sch-M lock, you will wait for all running queries to complete, any new query will be blocked behind your Sch-M lock request.

Before SQL 2012 this behavior was slightly different, as NOLOCK/READ UNCOMMITTED queries were able to acquire Sch-S locks while you wait for your Sch-M, and so you might have to wait forever.

In either case the result is that if there are lots of long-running queries against the table, the TRUNCATE or DROP will both take some time, and block other queries while it waits.

Normally this isn't a big deal.  If you are DROPing or TRUNCATEing a table, it's unlikely that other sessions will have running queries against it, or need to run new queries that reference it.

For scenarios where a metadata operation needs to be performed on a busy table SQL Server introduced "Low Priority Schema Lock Waits" in SQL 2014.  This allows ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX to wait for a Sch-M lock without blocking new requests.  The session just waits for a lull in the activity, an instant where no session owns a Sch-S lock, and then makes the change. See [New functionality in SQL Server 2014 – Part 3 – Low Priority Wait](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2014/01/17/new-functionality-in-sql-server-2014-part-3-low-priority-wait/) for a detailed explanation of the functionality, the history of how Schema locks behaved before SQL 2012, and the motivation for the enhancement.

Anyway in the unlikely event that you need low priority waits for TRUNCATE table, you can replicate it with ALTER TABLE … SWITCH to a staging table, followed by DROPping the staging table.  EG

```
create table t_stage ...;

alter table t   
switch to t_stage
with ( wait_at_low_priority ( max_duration = 4 minutes, abort_after_wait = self ) )  

drop table t_stage
```

Comment: OP said he has MySQL database.

Comment: The question wasn't originally tagged as MySQL, and since there is no generic answer to this question, I just explained the SQL Server behavior.

Answer (score 3):

- MyISAM -- `DROP` is like a file delete.  `TRUNCATE` performs the C file action of removing all the data but leaving the file in existence.
- InnoDB with its own tablespace (cf `innodb_file_per_table`) -- like a file delete
- InnoDB *without* its own tablespace -- lots of blocks to free up; this could take time.

A file drop can be fast or not so fast, depending on the Operating system.  Some OS's run around freeing up the blocks right then and there; you have to wait.  And, because it is an OS operation, this *may* interfere with virtually anything else.  What OS?

"Minutes" seems long.  How many minutes?  How many GB?

Comment: The minutes comment wasn't a statement that he had tried this and things had been blocked for minutes, but the question - *could* things be blocked for that long?

Comment: @RDFozz - I have seen an annoying long number of seconds, but I did not stop what I was doing long enough to record the OS, the filesystem, HDD/SSD, and the size of the file being deleted.  I suspect a terabyte could take "minutes" on certain filesystems with HDD.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, `TRUCNATE` is implemented as a `DROP ... CREATE`. It requires a lock for the `DROP`, which it will wait for. It does not invoke `ON DELETE` triggers. It causes an implicit commit. Whether or not it's atomic depends on storage engine.

For more information read,

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html

Can it be time consuming? Yes. Is it less-safe than `DELETE`, but faster -- yes it's an optimization.